# Duplicating a div in html on a button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to duplicate a whole div on a button click. I've used javascript clone() in order to duplicate the div. I've found the code to do the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427094/how-can-i-duplicate-a-div-onclick-with-javascript).

I tried the same way. But I didn't get the result. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code

html:

```
<tr>
<div id="duplicater">
<tr>
<td>Service Type:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="servicetype" id="servicetype"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Amount:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"></td>
</tr>
</div>
<tr><td><button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Add More</button></td></tr>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function duplicate() 
{
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');   //alert("hi");
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
clone.id = "duplic" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
//original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aishwaryas/qp20747v/4/)

Comment: Start by rectifying your **invalid** markup.

Comment: i.e. `onlick` is a typo; and putting a div that cuts across tr elements is very messy. You also need to move `var i = 0` outside the function

Comment: I've corrected the code and avoided the tr elements in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aishwaryas/qp20747v/14/). But still i didn't get the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup is **invalid**. `tr` element can't have `div` child. `div` element can't have `tr` child. The markup should be something like:

```
<tr id="service">
    <td>
        <span>Service Type:</span>
        <input type="text" name="servicetype" id="servicetype">
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>Amount:</span>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also the attribute name is `onclick` not `onlick`. In the jsFiddle you choose one of the `no wrap ...` options otherwise JS interpreter can't find your function.

The `i` variable should be defined outside of the `duplicate` function otherwise the result is always `duplic1`, you could also use the length of the rows instead of a counter. Here is an example using `insertBefore` for inserting the cloned element before the last row:

```
function duplicate() {    
    var original = document.getElementById('service');
    var rows = original.parentNode.rows;
    var i = rows.length - 1;
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplic" + (i); // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, rows[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vgrvnn5/

Note that the descendant elements of the cloned element have IDs and your current code/logic doesn't consider this.

Comment: I found my mistake and thanks for your valuable points. Now i got the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup should be like the following. i.e table rows should only contain table cells (`<th>`,`<td>`).

`<table>` should not have `<div>`'s as direct child, For grouping `<td>` elements you can use `<tbody>`

```
<table>
 <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="addmore" onclick="duplicate()">Add More</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody id="service">
    <tr>
        <td>Service Type:
            <input type="text" name="servicetype" id="servicetype" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount:
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Corresponding script will be:

```
var i = 0;
function duplicate() {
  var table = document.querySelector("table"),
      original = document.getElementById('service'),
      clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "duplic" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  table.appendChild(clone);
}
```

---

- You have a typo in the `onclick` as pointed out in comments.
- The counter should be outside the function
- JSFiddle wraps the script in an onload function if it is set to run `onload`, so inline handlers will not work. You should either set the fiddle script to `no-wrap` or explicitly declare the function to be global like `window.duplicate = function(){}`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp20747v/18/)