# Copy the contents of a div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy the data from one div to another div by using `JS` .

```
$(".second_div").html($(".first_div").html())
```

It will be done but `JS` code that is written in the `first_div` , would not be copied in `second_div` and it does not work in `second_div`. How can I copy `first_div` into `second_div` and remove the `first_div`?

ex.

```
<div class="first_div">
<span>text_test</span>
<span onclick="myfunction(this)">send</span>
</div>

js:
function myfunction(e){
console.log('ok')
}

<div class="second_div">
<span>text_test</span>
<span onclick="myfunction(this)">send</span> /// It does not work
</div>
```

Comment: `but JS code that is written in the first_div , would not be copied` can you explain ?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] - we need to know what you meant by JS code.

Comment: @Madhawa I try to explain more in above example,  `myfunction ` does not work for `second_div`

Comment: @sahar check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427094/how-can-i-duplicate-a-div-onclick-with-javascript